# Error in passing SQL command through a prepared statement via jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, sqlexception

I am trying to create table where the program gets the number of rows and columns during runtime.

Here's the code:

```
String sql = 
  "CREATE TABLE if not exists itemset (?";
up1 = con.prepareStatement(sql);
for(int j=1; j < ccolumns; j++) {
  sql += ",?";
}
sql += ")";
System.out.println(sql);
for(int j=1; j < ccolumns+1; j++) {
  System.out.println(j);
  up1.setString(j, "item"+j+" TINYINT(10)");
}
up1.executeQuery();
```

The error is

`Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1)`

It occurs in the setString line during the second iteration

Comment: Maybe you ought to call "prepare" *after* you finish building the SQL string ;)?

Comment: PreparedStatement should not be used for CREATE TABLE sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PreparedStatement` can't be used for DDL queries like the `CREATE TABLE` in the question.

The values passed to `setString()` get escaped in the resulting SQL, resulting in an invalid query sent to the database.

When only the number of columns is given, just create the CREATE TABLE statement (use a `StringBuilder` as others suggested) and execute it with a plain `Statement`, no need for a `PreparedStatement`:

```
String getCreateTableSql(int columns) {
  StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS itemset (");
  for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    if (i > 0) {
      sql.append(", ");
    }
    sql.append("item").append(i + 1).append(" TINYINT(10)");
  }
  sql.append(")");
  return sql.toString();
}
```

For 4 columns, this will output:

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS itemset (item1 TINYINT(10), item2 TINYINT(10), item3 TINYINT(10), item4 TINYINT(10))`

Comment: Yeah the plain statement is working, but i wanted to try the prepare statement.anyways thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try to move

```
up1 = con.prepareStatement(sql);
```

After

```
System.out.println(sql);
```

Comment: That indeed solved the earlier problem but now it gives a new problem

For a ccolumns input of 5,the sql statement seems to be have been changed to

 ''item1 TINYINT(10)','item2 TINYINT(10)','item3 TINYINT(10)','item4 TINYINT(10)','

instead of 4 there has to be 5 of these (The second loop is being iterated 5times )

Answer (score 1):

First thing what you want to fix is please don't use `String` instance when you want to change it. `String` intance is immutable and when you modify already created `String`, new modified instance is created and it is not free.
You should to use `StringBuilder` for this that have instance methods which allow to modify it without need to create new instance. I recommend to you use always `StringBuilder` when you modifying `String`. and second so you call `con.prepareStatement(sql)` and then you modify its sql field. it's not good is't?
So only add it after your work with String.

```
String sql = 
  "CREATE TABLE if not exists itemset (?";
for(int j=1; j < ccolumns; j++) {
  sql += ",?";
}
sql += ")";
System.out.println(sql);
up1 = con.prepareStatement(sql);
for(int j=1; j < ccolumns+1; j++) {
  System.out.println(j);
  up1.setString(j, "item"+j+" TINYINT(10)");
}
up1.executeQuery();
```

You cannot call `prepareStatement` with given `String` and then modify it.

---

But more cleaner and faster try to do it like this

```
StringBuilder sqlStatement = new StringBuilder(
      "CREATE TABLE if not exists itemset (?");
    for(int j=1; j < ccolumns; j++) {
      sqlStatement.append(",?");
    }
    sqlStatement.append(")");
    up1 = con.prepareStatement(sqlStatement.toString());
    for(int j=1; j < ccolumns+1; j++) {
      System.out.println(j);
      up1.setString(j, "item"+j+" TINYINT(10)");
    }
    up1.executeQuery();
```

Comment: @PhilippReichart sorry, bad replace immediately i saw it, corrected.

Comment: The error is in giving the preparestatement before the string,by using the StringBuilder it stills give the problem i have mentioned in reply to andriy,anyways i didnt know abt the StringBuilder thanks

Answer (score 1):

Though I didn't verify it, I believe that Andriy's answer is correct. Additionally, you may want to consider using a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) for String accumulation, as they are lighter-weight. Updated code below.

```
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("CREATE TABLE if not exists itemset (?");
    for (int j = 1; j < ccolumns; j++) {
        sql.append(",?");
    }
    sql.append(")");
    System.out.println(sql.toString());
    up1 = con.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
    for (int j = 1; j < ccolumns + 1; j++) {
        System.out.println(j);
        up1.setString(j, "item" + j + " TINYINT(10)");
    }
    up1.executeQuery();
```